# iOS- Pull HTML id to display an image in an UIImageView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need to be able to pull the line of HTML below from my website and display the image in the imageView I have in my Storyboard. I already Have some code on how to pull text from the same website, could I use something like the other piece of code? Of course, without the striped part, that is only to get plain text. I would just load the link to the image, but the image changes depending on the song playing. I want to try and avoid just displaying the image in a UIWebView, I would much rather prefer displaying it in a UIImageView

HTML code:

```
<div id="album_cover"> 
<img height="160px" width="160px" id="imgcover" src="Link to image changed based on the song playing" alt="Loading..."></div>
```

Objective C code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.urlForLink = @"http://cloudrad.io/pointzeroradio/player";
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [self.urlForLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [webViewForRecents loadRequest:request];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(recentTracksText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)recentTracksText {

NSString *textForBlog = [webViewForRecents stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('current_song').textContent;"];

// Add this step for stripping the HTML from the text you received
self.strippedTextForBlog = [self stringByStrippingHTMLFromString:textForBlog];

continuousLabel.text = self.strippedTextForBlog;


}
```

Based off of elio.d answer. This works great for me and loads anywhere from 30 seconds to 3 minutes. If anyone has a way that will load quickly.

```
-(void)getImageCover {

    NSString * js      = @"document.getElementById('imgcover').src;";
    NSString * imgLink = [webViewForRecents stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    NSURL    * imgURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:imgLink];

    dispatch_queue_t exampleQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
    dispatch_async(exampleQueue, ^{

        NSData  * imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
        UIImage * image   = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

            [imageView setImage:image];

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: which part is slow? the download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your div contains just an image

If so, this is how you could implement:

```
-(void)getImageCover {
   NSString * js      = @"document.getElementById("imgcover").src;"
   NSString * imgLink = [webViewForRecents stringByEvaluatingString:js];
   NSURL    * imgURL  = [NSURL urlWithString:imgLink];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
     NSData  * imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
     UIImage * image   = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
       [imageView setImage:image];
     });
   });
}
```